# Delphi remote debugger not working over a WAN connection

Tags: delphi, remote-debugging, wan

I am trying to perform a remote debug over the internet, however, I receive the following error.

**Error**

> ```
> Debugger Assertion Failure: "!"mkapistream::openConnection()""
> in ..\win32src\rproxy.cpp at line 298
> OK
> ```

Details >>

I have opened up the default PAServer port i.e. 64211, as well as the remote debugger port i.e. 64447 on my router and, can confirm that they are available from an external source.

I have tried with both Delphi XE3 which is my development environment as well as with a trial version of the new Delphi 10.3, however, both versions of Delphi throw the exact same error.

This error occurs, when I try using the `Load Process|Remote` and `Attach to Process|Remote`.

If I attempt the exact same process over a LAN connection everything works as expected, it only seems to be over a WAN which the problem occurs.

Below are my environment details:

> Windows 10 - Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.2608)
>
> Delphi XE3 Update 2 Enterprise - Version 17.0.4770.56661
>
> PA Server (paserver.exe) - Version 17.0.4770.56661
>
> Remote debugger (rmtdbg170.exe) - Version 17.0.4770.56661

and

> Delphi 10.3 Architect Trial - Version 26.0.32429.4364
>
> PA Server (paserver.exe) - Version 26.0.32429.4364
>
> Remote Debugger (rmtdbg260.exe) - Version 260.1810.29.29349

I have also registered both libraries `bordbk170.dll` and `bordbk170N.dll` for Delphi XE3 as well as `bordbk260.dll` and `bordbk260N.dll`.

If I set up an VPN connection, I can remote debug over the WAN connection, but it seems as if the remote debugger just cannot resolve the cons over a straight WAN connection.

So, my question is the following:

**Can one remote debug a Delphi application over a WAN connection?**

Comment: You could not directly, I guess, without tuning some firewall settings, but it should be feasible using a tunneled connection (like a VPN or a ssh session).

Comment: this is as expected, due to how a WAN (and the whole Internet) works

Comment: What is strange is the deployment manager works just fine over the WAN, so I am able to build and deploy the files over the WAN, so the communication between the IDE and the PAServer is fine, and a new instance of the remote debugger is successfully started on the remote machine once i attempt to remote debug, however the remote debugging itself fails?

Comment: i guess its not working because on windos hosts the pa server spawns rmtdbg###.exe on one fixed port and a random port for each debug connection. And that random Port seems to me to be the Problem. (Iam fighting with something like that for remote debugging in a container)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to find out what port the remote debugger is looking for and redirect that using port forwarding on your local router to your PC

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by configuring the remote system's firewall: after I opened all TCP ports for incoming connections, debugging works as expected.

My configuration is:

- Lokal: Delphi 10.2 on Windows 10 Pro
- Remote: Windows Server 2019
- Connected over RDP and VPN connection